# Sort Order Management - Not Satistfied with SortOrder * 10^n or Linked List Implementation

Tags: sql, sorting

I have sibling data that users need to define an "official" order for, NOT alphabetical order by some name, by date created/posted, by value (such as salary, sales, or rank).

**SortOrder * 1^n**

I figure such sortable object would need to have an integer `SortOrder` column where lesser values mean closer to the first item (`SortOrder = 1` means first item).

Many have suggested to automatically assign `SortOrder = newId * 1000` (n = 3) when inserting a new record. Later down the line, we would insert a record between two records, and the inserted record's sort order would be set to

```
inserted.SortOrder = (previous.SortOrder + next.SortOrder) / 2
```

Yeah, but do this enough times, you'll run out of "precision" - what sort order would you assign to an inserted record when previous.SortOrder = 3000 and next.SortOrder = 3001?

Increase the n value, you'll just delay the problem.

---

**Linked List Implementation**

Some suggest to have a `NextRecordId`. This way, we have a "trail" of records. Inserting a record between two only requires two updates -

```
previous.NextRecordId = inserted.Id
inserted.NextRecordId = next.Id
```

And the items following `next` won't be affected.

This seems like a good proposal, but there are problems.

How do you pull the data to display in the correct order? `ORDER BY NextRecordId` (either `ASC` or `DESC`) won't work. For `ORDER BY ASC`, it will first pick records whose NextRecordId is the smallest. That's not the order we want.

It seems like we have to iterate (in a stored procedure), and each iteration will require a `SELECT WHERE Id=@CurrentNextRecordId`, then put each result in a new table.

How would you keep track of which record is the first - have a bit `IsFirst` column, or have a `FirstChildRecordId` in a parent table? We can say that the record with `NextRecordId = 0` is the last one. It seems like creating columns in a database to implement data structures isn't a good idea, no?

---

So, I'm stuck on this, and I've searched through this forum and online - can't find a good solution. All of them seem to require some sort of post-maintenance (reseeding, but how do you determine when) or potentially expensive computation (update the sort order of all records after the insertion index) per sort "move".

Any new insight or tricks to this?

Answer (score 1):

One method to have a flexible sort order is to use character strings, rather than numbers.

Initially assign zero-padded numbers as the sort order:  `'001'`, `'002'` . . .

Then, when you want to add something between two values, just add a `5` to the value.  The sorting for strings puts `'001'`, `'0015'`, and `'002'` in the order you want.

Of course, you can make this more efficient by testing the last digit.  If it is a `'5'`, and you want something bigger, put in 7 or 8.  You can also make this more efficient by expanding the character set to include letters as well as numbers.